# After shutdown, Ubuntu fails to start with fsck prompt

Tags: boot, startup, fsck

I forgot to plug in the charger and my system shut down. After that I tried to start Ubuntu, but the HP logo was showing up for too long so I forced shutdown by pressing power button. After that this error showed up.

```
Error reading block 1315...(input/output error)
Run fsck manually
```

This error showed up:

[image: This is showing up]

Comment: This is not a purely `fsck` question. This needs an `fsck` and a `NCQ` patch and maybe a bad blocking. If they reopen the question, I can provide a complete answer.

Comment: Yogi... are you still there?

Comment: I found my solution in already asked question, so I approved it and my question became duplicate. However I faced same problem 2nd time yesterday and used same approch to solve the issue. Thanks for your concern

Comment: Please tell me how you've been fixing it. As I mentioned in my previous comment, you probably have more than one problem, but I can't write an answer as they've closed the question. I've asked that it be reopened. Edit your question, add details about what you've done so far, and maybe it'll help reopen the question.

Comment: Try clicking on **reopen** and see if that reopens the question.

Comment: I ran `fsck -y /dev/sda10`. It fixed errors and I was able to start PC by typing `bootup`

Comment: Good! Now do the rest of my answer. Report back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**fsck**

Let's first repair your file system...

- at the (initramfs) prompt, type: `fsck -f /dev/sda10`
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

**NCQ**

Then we stop the NCQ errors...

Native Command Queuing (NCQ) is an extension of the Serial ATA protocol allowing hard disk drives to internally optimize the order in which received read and write commands are executed.

Edit `sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub` and change the following line to include this extra parameter (ignore any warning messages). Then do `sudo update-grub` to write the changes to disk. `Reboot`. Monitor hangs, and watch `/var/log/syslog` or `dmesg` for continued error messages.

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash libata.force=noncq"
```

**bad blocking**

Then we test for bad blocks on the disk...

Note: do NOT abort a bad block scan!

Note: do NOT bad block a SSD

Note: backup your important files FIRST!

Note: this will take many hours

Note: you may have a pending HDD failure

Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode.

In `terminal`...

`sudo fdisk -l` # identify all "Linux Filesystem" partitions

<strike>`sudo e2fsck -fcky /dev/sdXX` # read-only test</strike>

or

`sudo e2fsck -fccky /dev/sdXX` # non-destructive read/write test **(recommended)**

The -k is important, because it saves the previous bad block table, and adds any new bad blocks to that table. Without -k, you loose all of the prior bad block information.

The -fccky parameter...

```
   -f    Force checking even if the file system seems clean.

   -c    This option causes e2fsck to use badblocks(8) program  to  do  a
         read-only  scan  of  the device in order to find any bad blocks.
         If any bad blocks are found, they are added  to  the  bad  block
         inode  to  prevent them from being allocated to a file or direc‐
         tory.  If this option is specified twice,  then  the  bad  block
         scan will be done using a non-destructive read-write test.

   -k    When combined with the -c option, any existing bad blocks in the
         bad blocks list are preserved, and any new bad blocks  found  by
         running  badblocks(8)  will  be added to the existing bad blocks
         list.

   -y    Assume  an answer of `yes' to all questions; allows e2fsck to be
         used non-interactively.  This option may not be specified at the
         same time as the -n or -p options.
```